# CSS Box shadow not appearing on element with same class

Tags: html, css

I'm making a portfolio website for a school assignment but i'm running into a annoying little thing. I've got two elements with both the same class. I've defined a drop shadow for this class with css, the first element is showing the box shadow but the second doesn't...

To me it seems logical that both elements should have a shadow now..
Here is the webpage: http://wouterjanson.nl

Here is the section of the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <main class="content">
        <article class="content_item">
            <img src="img/post_img_home.png" alt="Html code">
                <h1>Home - Portfolio Wouter Janson</h1>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent tempor lorem sit amet quam condimentum pretium. Etiam quis odio a nisl varius rutrum. Maecenas mattis mi ac est finibus, quis pulvinar lacus finibus. Mauris id dui nunc. Donec ornare eros a laoreet rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam eget libero metus. Etiam at rhoncus metus, non condimentum erat. Sed sed sodales turpis, lacinia bibendum nisl. Integer sagittis metus quis lectus auctor, et elementum nisl pretium. Nulla facilisi. Proin lobortis leo nisl, a consequat turpis ullamcorper eget. Curabitur quis bibendum odio.</p>
        </article>
        <article class="content_item">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent tempor lorem sit amet quam condimentum pretium. Etiam quis odio a nisl varius rutrum. Maecenas mattis mi ac est finibus, quis pulvinar lacus finibus. Mauris id dui nunc. Donec ornare eros a laoreet rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam eget libero metus. Etiam at rhoncus metus, non condimentum erat. Sed sed sodales turpis, lacinia bibendum nisl. Integer sagittis metus quis lectus auctor, et elementum nisl pretium. Nulla facilisi. Proin lobortis leo nisl, a consequat turpis ullamcorper eget. Curabitur quis bibendum odio.</p>
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS class:

```
.container {
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.content_item {
   background-color: #ffffff;
   border-radius: 4px;
   box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(145, 145, 145, 0.5);
   margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Both have a drop shadow when tested: http://jsfiddle.net/xfd59q0v/1/

Comment: Indeed - http://jsfiddle.net/xy53e138/

Comment: I see it's working.. But not on my site, the first page is visible online: http://wouterjanson.nl as you can see the second element doesn't has a drop shadow..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `overflow:hidden` on your container element. Just remove it.

```
.container {
width: 100%;
float: left;
/* overflow: hidden; */
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have give `padding-bottom` on container

```
.container {
width: 100%;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
margin-bottom: 30px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

but the content div (the parent of .content_item) to 582 instead of 479 :)
`.content{height: 582px;}`